# Delay in C#/Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to do a delay in Unity, because the Object should not get destroyed immediately.
Note: `yield WaitForSeconds (0.25);` doesn't work for me. It gives many errors like

> ; expected

even if I have one.

Here is the Source code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyObject : MonoBehaviour
{
     void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
     {
         if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
         {
            //Here 2 Seconds Delay
            Destroy(gameObject);
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for destroy more. It has a delay option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter for Destroy() method can take a float as a delay before destroying like:

```
Destroy(gameObject, 2F);
```

Comment: @YodaMaster445 then please go through the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and mark this answer as accepted if it helped you. Note though that the other answer is also correct as you simply used `WaitForSeconds` the wrong way